# What is the correct version of Google Play Services needed for Firebase Performance Monitoring?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services

I'm trying to integrate **Firebase Performance Monitoring** on an application in which I have already successfully installed Firebase (in fact, I'm already using Crashlytics in this app).

The documentation states that in order to use Firebase Performance Monitoring, the device must have **Google Play Services** installed.

However, my problem is that I've found what appears to be a bunch of inconsistencies between the documentation and the actual version of Google Play Services available in the Play Store.

- The [prerequisites section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#prerequisites) of the documentation states:

> Before you begin, you need a few things set up in your environment:
>
> - A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and **Google Play services 16.1.2 or higher**

- Also, [further in that same page](http://https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-androidcheck-thefirebase-console-for-performance-monitoring-results), it says:

> Test your app using an Android emulator with a recent image and **Google Play services 15.0.0** or later, or using a test device with **Google Play services 15.0.0 or later**.

- On the other hand, the Play Store app on my device (running Android 6.0.1) shows that I have Google Play Services **up-to-date**, having version **13.2.80**, updated on **September 6th, 2018**:
  [image: Google Play Services version: 13.2.80. Updated on September 6th, 2018.]
- On top of that, [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/) shows that the most recent stable version to the date is **14.3.66, updated on October 3rd, 2018**
- Nevertheless, [the official release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#play_services_updates) show that **there are no 13.2.80  or 14.3.66 versions**  and that starting on version **15.0.0**, launched on April 12th (almost six months *before* **13.2.80**!), they use SemVer with different versions for their different products.

So my question is: **how do I get the correct version of Google Play Services needed for Firebase Performance Monitoring installed on my device?**

Any clarifications on why this 13.2.80 version that I have installed or the 14.3.66 version provided in APK Mirror are not mentioned in the official release notes would be appreciated, too.

Comment: Play Services' app version name doesn't correspond to the latest Play Services Gradle dependency version. Just use the latest version of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have not got an update by Google on your device (6.0.1), latest versions of Android OS are updated to the stable version of Google play services 14.3.66. So you can test your application on emulators or any other devices.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, but that doesn't explain why the docs talk about 15.0.0 and  16.1.2